# How do I stop the newline that a button makes in html?

Tags: html, css

So I have made a website, and I have a h1 but, i want to add buttons to the right of the h1 but when I add the button it creates in below the h1, I just cant figure out how to stop the newline.

I looked all over the internet but no one had this problem, i tried to switch  to  but it gave the same problem...

Comment: see float in css. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: When asking a question about HTML, CSS and/or JavaScript, please tale the time to post the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code in the question in order to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

headers are block elements by default, so they're displayed in separate blocks unlike inline elements
you can overwrite this default behavior by specifying h1 as an inline-block

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some Header</h1>
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two display values in HTML: block and inline.
Every HTML element has a default display value.

Headings - are block level elements.
So, they always start on a new line by default.

So, you could do something like this to solve the problem:

```
<h1 style="display:inline">heading</h1>
<button type="submit">Click</button>
```

Comment: Just wanna add, that there are a few more possible values for `display` than just `block` and `inline`. -> [CSS Display property - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to align the buttons? If you want it centred vertically I'd do this:

```css
.h1andbutton {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="h1andbutton">
<h1>Title</h1>
<button>Test</button>
<button>Another Button</button>
</div>
```